# abstract algebra for component wise operations on "vectors" or what it might be called

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

I have a quite tough problem to solve and need an algebra that allows to "vectors" following operations:
- multiplication between two vectors are componentwise that means v=(v1, v2, v3,...) multiplied by w=(w1, w2, w3,...) gives v.w = (v1 w1, v2 w2, v3 w3,...)
- no scalar multiplication of vectors allowed
- all mathematical operators suc as log, sin, cos, sign, etc are applied componentwise
- the vectors contain only integers
In general every operation seems to work here component wise. Indeed I do not even like to call them even a vector. 
Formally, I need to fix what type of ring/module/... and properties define exactly this algebra and what terminology I can use.
It is crazy that I have solved the problem but can not expressit in a formal language, because of lacking as from natural sciences the mathematical formalism from abstract algebra.
Is there anybody who can help me please.
Many thanks
-Sam

Comment: Since all of the operations are one component at a time, the resulting equations just involve separate copies of the real number line (or whatever ring your scalars live in), so it is just usual algebra of real numbers (or whatever ring your scalars live in).

Comment: An extremely similar question was asked here before: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9166. My preferred to think of $n$-vectors in this context as real-valued functions on a discrete space with $n$ points.

Comment: Perhaps looking up "Cartsian product" or "direct product" of algebras will help.  My guess is that the algebra you want is
sometimes called $R \times R$ .  Gerhard "Ask Me About General Algebra" Paseman, 2013.03.18

Comment: Sorry: Cartesian.   Gerhard "Smartphone Keyboards Are Too Small" Paseman, 2013.03.18

Comment: How can the vectors only contain integers, yet you want to take $\sin$?

Comment: Allen, he may want to round down, or for certain operations may wish to map his elements into a different algebra.  However, to me the post seems to have a naive point of view and, as the poster seems to admit, is struggling to find the right terms to describe what is wanted.  Hopefully the question will be edited and Sam or someone else will add clarity.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.03.18

Comment: the vectors contain only natural numbers; like v=(3,4,6,7,9,...)
so the sin, sign or ln applies to each of the components like ln(v)=(ln3, ln4, ln6, ln7, ln9...). The same with other operands.
Sorrz trogonometric operands do not occur (sorry my error). The main operands are ln of a vector and the multiplication of two vectors.
The component wise multiplication I guess would mean (Hadamrd type) a non-integral domain. A kind of F(n) as a ring instead of a vector space over F, coordinate wise multiplication -> Product Ring structure of the Ring F
I would really appreciate any help or idea.